# Creating a column of unique identifiers and sequencing along subjects

Tags: r

I have a data set where I am attempting to sequence along subject observations and then create a column that provides their birth year. The data looks like this:

```
Name <- c("Joe Smith", "Joe Smith","Joe Smith","Joe Smith", "Tom Watson", "Tom Watson", "Tom Watson", "Carl Nelle", "Carl Nelle", "Carl Nelle", "Carl Nelle", "Joe Smith", "Joe Smith", "Joe Smith", "Joe Smith")
Year <- c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000)
Var1 <- round(rnorm(n = Name, mean = 10, sd = 2),1)
Var2 <- round(rnorm(n = Name, mean = 30, sd = 10),0)

data <- data.frame(Name, Year, Var1, Var2)
data

         Name Year Var1 Var2
1   Joe Smith 2001  8.9   23
2   Joe Smith 2002  9.8   45
3   Joe Smith 2003 11.1   43
4   Joe Smith 2004 11.7   63
5  Tom Watson 2014 11.7   47
6  Tom Watson 2015 13.2   28
7  Tom Watson 2016  9.5   30
8  Carl Nelle 2006  9.5   44
9  Carl Nelle 2007 11.2   32
10 Carl Nelle 2008 12.2   24
11 Carl Nelle 2009  5.6   15
12  Joe Smith 1997 10.5   38
13  Joe Smith 1998 10.3   14
14  Joe Smith 1999  9.2   27
15  Joe Smith 2000  7.1   49
```

I used the `dplyr` package to create my sequence of each observation for the subjects like so:

```
data <- data %>%
        group_by(Name) %>%
        mutate(id = row_number())

         Name Year Var1 Var2 id
1   Joe Smith 2001  8.9   23  1
2   Joe Smith 2002  9.8   45  2
3   Joe Smith 2003 11.1   43  3
4   Joe Smith 2004 11.7   63  4
5  Tom Watson 2014 11.7   47  1
6  Tom Watson 2015 13.2   28  2
7  Tom Watson 2016  9.5   30  3
8  Carl Nelle 2006  9.5   44  1
9  Carl Nelle 2007 11.2   32  2
10 Carl Nelle 2008 12.2   24  3
11 Carl Nelle 2009  5.6   15  4
12  Joe Smith 1997 10.5   38  5
13  Joe Smith 1998 10.3   14  6
14  Joe Smith 1999  9.2   27  7
15  Joe Smith 2000  7.1   49  8
```

My first problem with this is that the second Joe Smith doesn't get his own id number. This is a problem as several people in the dataset can have the same name. Is there a way to correct this?

The second issue is that I need to create a column called "Birth.Year" which is represented as the first year that the person is in the data base. So it would look like this:

```
         Name Year Var1 Var2 id Birth.Year
1   Joe Smith 2001  8.9   23  1       2001
2   Joe Smith 2002  9.8   45  2       2001
3   Joe Smith 2003 11.1   43  3       2001
4   Joe Smith 2004 11.7   63  4       2001
5  Tom Watson 2014 11.7   47  1       2014
6  Tom Watson 2015 13.2   28  2       2014
7  Tom Watson 2016  9.5   30  3       2014
8  Carl Nelle 2006  9.5   44  1       2006
9  Carl Nelle 2007 11.2   32  2       2006
10 Carl Nelle 2008 12.2   24  3       2006
11 Carl Nelle 2009  5.6   15  4       2006
12  Joe Smith 1997 10.5   38  5       1997
13  Joe Smith 1998 10.3   14  6       1997
14  Joe Smith 1999  9.2   27  7       1997
15  Joe Smith 2000  7.1   49  8       1997
```

Is there a way to accomplish these tasks in dplyr or do I need to write a specific function?

Comment: If you are guaranteed that each person will be grouped together, then you may be able to *infer* grouping that way (but no guarantee). Otherwise, given the data you've provided, there are no assured ways to distinguish between the two different "Joe Smith"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the `lag` function. Note that we need to replace the first instance (which is NA) with `FALSE`. The use of the `lag` function allows us to check if the `Name` matches the previous `Name` or not.

This solution assumes that if the Names aren't grouped together, they're different people.

```
data <- data.frame(Name, Year, Var1, Var2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data %>%
    mutate(Foo1 = Name != lag(Name),
           Foo2 = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(Foo1), FALSE, Foo1))) %>%
    group_by(Name, Foo2) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           BirthYear = min(Year))

         Name  Year  Var1  Var2  Foo1  Foo2    id BirthYear
        <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <int> <int>     <dbl>
1   Joe Smith  2001   9.0    30    NA     0     1      2001
2   Joe Smith  2002  11.8    47 FALSE     0     2      2001
3   Joe Smith  2003   6.9    23 FALSE     0     3      2001
4   Joe Smith  2004   8.6    37 FALSE     0     4      2001
5  Tom Watson  2014  10.7    35  TRUE     1     1      2014
6  Tom Watson  2015   9.4    30 FALSE     1     2      2014
7  Tom Watson  2016   7.5    25 FALSE     1     3      2014
8  Carl Nelle  2006  10.7    32  TRUE     2     1      2006
9  Carl Nelle  2007   6.6    25 FALSE     2     2      2006
10 Carl Nelle  2008  10.9    34 FALSE     2     3      2006
11 Carl Nelle  2009  13.5    18 FALSE     2     4      2006
12  Joe Smith  1997  10.1    34  TRUE     3     1      1997
13  Joe Smith  1998  12.0    34 FALSE     3     2      1997
14  Joe Smith  1999   7.3    40 FALSE     3     3      1997
15  Joe Smith  2000  10.8    26 FALSE     3     4      1997
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great! It worked. Quick question, why did it only work when you put the stringAsFactors = F argument in the data.frame( ) function? If I use the original data frame I created it doesn't produce the proper output?